# Placeholder for deactivated input[type="text"] in IE 10/11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

**Situation 1**

Why is the placeholder selectable in a deactivated `input[type="text"]`?

```
<input name="minMax2" disabled="disabled" id="minMax2" type="text"  
                      placeholder="min. 100 / max. 200" min="100" max="200">
```

**Situation 2**

I've even have a weird situation where I can type text into the placeholder but this does happens if I click into a text field which is deactivated but because I've left another field and an attached change event did enable the datepicker.

[image]

Any idea? Did I miss something or is this a bug of Internet Explorer 10 and 11?

Comment: Why is this marked to be closed?

Comment: Why are you set disabled="disabled" attributes?

Comment: What is the alternative to `disabled="disabled"`? I'm just using JSF's `<h:inputText` to (initial) disable the text field which is using that attribute.

Comment: I can select the placeholder text in IE11. Looks like a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes to your jsfiddle from what I understand to be your problem. In your jsfiddle you included jQuery so I thought I would add to your script. I have just changed how you have declared disabled in your input and also made a change to your script so that it now removes the disabled attribute on focus.

```
$('#test3').prop("disabled", false).focus();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a8ezd/3/

If you want to go further and make it so that the user can't even select the placeholder slightly when it's e.g. disabled then you could alter the user select in the css by adding the following with the appropriate browser prefix:

```
user-select:none;
```

Example of that here:

http://jsfiddle.net/a8ezd/4/

Comment: Looks like your second suggestion works in IE11 very well. Tmrw back at work I will test it in our project code and with IE10. Thank you! BTW your first suggestions does not apply for our use case since the user must not click into the next text field (but he can).

Comment: By "the user must not click into the next field (but they can)" do you mean that the field should permanently stay disabled?

Comment: No, as soon as the "leaving" field is valid the disabled field should be enabled. But it's not guaranteed that the user clicks into the second field rather than to another section of the page. It's actually a date range field pair. If one field contains a non-valid value, the other one is disabled.

Comment: I've tried the `user-select` variant which does work in the jsfiddle but not in my code. I'm still able to edit the placeholder... :-/ The field is acutally a (JQuery) date picker, maybe I've to take this into account but I don't see why this should be different since it's still a `input[type="text"]` field with a HTML5 placeholder.

Comment: If you want the field to become enabled as soon as it complies with your validation you could use .on('keyup', function(){}) http://jsfiddle.net/a8ezd/5/

Comment: With user select did you include all of the browser prefixes that I had in my example?

Comment: Hi Dan. Yes, I've added all browser prefixes, even more. However, your second last comment is a great workaround for my issue. It does not solve the main problem which I think is a bug but works well with our code. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a browser behavior. As an alternative you can keep it enabled (style it appropriately as disabled if needed) and add attribute `onfocus="this.blur()"`

Here's your demo modified: http://jsfiddle.net/a8ezd/1/

Comment: It's a proper workaround. Since we're using JSF it's not the best way to go. However, I'll check your suggestion tmrw together with Dan's user-select variant. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Yuriy. Dan's answer did solve my issue with a workaround. Thank you for your answer too!